# Passing UseState from child component to parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to pass up the state "region" defined in my useState Hook to the parent element. Im not sure where to put the word region in order to do that though?

This is the Child Element

```
import React from 'react';

export default function SimpleMenu() {

  const [region, setRegion] = useState("Africa");

  const filterRegion = (e) => {
    setRegion(e.target.value);
  };  

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Filter by Region
      </Button>
      <Menu>
        <MenuItem onClick={ filterRegion } >Africa</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={ filterRegion }>America</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={ filterRegion }>Asia</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={ filterRegion }>Europe</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={ filterRegion }>Oceania</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the parent element:

```
state = {
  countries: [],
  renderedCountries: "Africa",
  selectedCountries: null
}
  
<div id="search_dropdown">
   <Menu countries = renderedCountries = {this.state.renderedCountries}/>
</div>
```

Comment: If you copied the entirety of you code (imports & file-names) into your post I'd attempt to debug it. For instance, I don't know if your parent is a class or function component. Also, it seems to be rendering `Menu` but you've named your child-component `SimpleMenu`. Have you remembered to import `SimpleMenu` into your parent component? With that being said, one solution to your problem is to pass down a prop, that's a method, from parent to child. Then you execute that method in child, giving it the argument you want (in this case, `region`).

Answer (score 1):

> Passing UseState from child component to parent component?

No you shouldn't. This is an anti-pattern of React's [Data Flows Down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).

If you want both the parent and child component make use of `region` state, you should [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) instead.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: 'Africa' // region is owned by Parent component
    }
  }

  // class field syntax
  updateRegion = (region) => {
    this.setState({ region });
  }

  render() {
     // Pass region state down as prop
     // Also provide an updater function for setting region in child component
     return (
       <div id="search_dropdown">
         <Menu updateRegion={this.updateRegion} region={this.state.region} />
       </div>
     );
  }
}
```