# In REACT.js how can I pass a state from child component up to Parent component as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-component

Im trying to pass a state from a classless child component as a prop to a parent class component.
How can I get "region", in Parent's state, to update every time a new region is selected from the drop down "Menu" in the child component?

Parent Component:

IMPORTS:

```
import '../Styles/App.css';
import Menu from './Menu';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import CountryList from './CountryList';
```

Parent's State:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    countries: [],
    region: "Africa",
  }
```

Fetching API

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const apiURL = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`;
      const response = fetch(apiURL)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            countries: data
          });
        })
  }
```

Rendering APP

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <section>
        <div id="search">
          <div id="search_box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a country..."/>
          </div>

          <div id="search_dropdown">
            <Menu />
          </div>
        </div>

        <CountryList countries = {this.state.countries} region = {this.state.region}/>
      </section>
    </div>
      )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Child Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

export default function SimpleMenu(props) {
  const [region, setRegion] = React.useState("Africa");

  return (
    <div>
      <Button>
        Filter by Region
      </Button>

      <Menu>
        <MenuItem> Africa </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem> America </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem> Asia </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem> Europe </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem> Oceania </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems you are posting the same question - [Passing UseState from child component to parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64601616/passing-usestate-from-child-component-to-parent-component)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function as a prop to child component and onchange call the prop function with new value.

// Sample callback function

```
  handleOnChange(value) {
     console.log(value);
  }
```

// Pass this function to child as a prop

```
<Menu handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state management like redux and mobx to pass state to another component